# Can you pick up a fever?

Tags: word-usage

> I picked up a fever last weekend.

Is the above sentence used the word  'picked up' correctly?

Comment: Do you have a definition that suggests you can use "pick up" in this way? Please provide a reference.

Comment: Google defines 'pick up' in so many ways including the following one: "catch an illness or infection.
"I've picked up some kind of flu bug". So I think it is appropriate for illness., But not sure if it fits well with the word fever. It might.

Comment: The question has *great* potential, but it needs to be fleshed out. Could you not say where you read or heard this expression, and explain "why" you think it may be "incorrect"?

Answer (score 1):

For diseases and sicknesses, one should normally use catch and caught , I personally hadn't seen "pick up" before diseases till in this case.

Answer (score 0):

*Pick up* can mean "to acquire incidentally or passively", e.g. "I dragged the net through the water and picked up seaweed."  As no one really intends to get a disease, this isn't really a wrong use of *pick up*.

However, diseases are generally *caught*, not *picked up.*

> Looks like Johnny caught a fever, he'll be staying home from school.

Comment: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pick-up#pick-up__19

Comment: See the example in that like.  Most tourists are worried that they’ll pick up a nasty stomach bug.